# Does it possible in SVN keep the same local copy for two SVN repositories?

Tags: svn, local

I need to use some features of SVN like branching, history, reverting, revisions for my local copy of code, but I would like commit to the server repository only sometime, when I have finished my local developing. Does it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the chapter on [Branching and Merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html) in the SVN book, since what you want to do sounds like a "feature branch". In short, only checking in locally is not possible with svn; you can, however, have an arbitrary number of working copies of the same repository on your local machine; and if you create your own branch on the server, the trunk will be unchanged until you merge your branch to it.

However, if you do stuff like this regularly, and really don't want to involve the server (or can't because you don't maintain or have access to it), I'd also recommend using git as another answer here already suggests.

Answer (score 3):

That's the model of Subversion: you make some development locally, test that everything is OK, and if ready, commit multiple changes at once in the repository.

If the modification is important and takes a long time, then you should split it in several short modifications, and commit those short modifications as soon as possible. If you don't want other developers on the trunk to see these modifications until everything is done, then create a feature branch, commit regularly in this feature branch, and then reintegrate the feature branch into the trunk.

This is well described in the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to implement the git workflow in svn. This is not possible, however if you have the ability to choose your VCS software you can try out git.